# Почему Яндекс.Переводчик выдаёт 404?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, яндекс-переводчик

Cкрипт переводчика стал выдавать ошибку 404. Пробовал разные ключи и с разных доменов запускать. Все равно не работает. Это я действительно что-то превысил, или где-то ошибка?

> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(45) "Maximum daily
> translated text volume exceeded" }

```
$url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20161214T114634Z.0492e7b1ebd2d3b4.57c088043e2306103d52f62d96bbf3893cac7554&text=close&lang=ru&format=plain&options=1';

$curlObject = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$responseData = curl_exec($curlObject);

curl_close($curlObject);

if ($responseData === false) {
    throw new Exception('Response false');
}

var_dump(json_decode($responseData, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Создай разные аккаунты и в них заведи по ключу. В классе сделай проверку на ошибку 404 и подставляй следующий ключ

Answer (score 0):

В бесплатном API Yandex Translate есть суточный лимит на количество символов. Пользуйтесь платной версией или используйте ресурс экономней. Расход лимита если не ошибаюсь можно было посмотреть где-то в личном кабинете.

Answer (score 0):

у яндекса больше нет бесплатного лимита на API переводчика